# Program to find if a string length is odd or even

Tags: java

I am creating a program to find out if a string that is entered has an odd or even amount of characters.  I am having trouble with the runner class, because whenever I enter a string, it just prints it back and doesn't carry out the different methods that I have in my main class. How do I call for the methods in the runner class?

MAIN CLASS:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class stringoddoreven
{
    private String word;

    public stringoddoreven()
    {
        setString("");
    }

    public stringoddoreven(String s)
    {
        setString(s);
    }

    public void setString(String s)
    {
        word = s;
    }

    public boolean isEven()
    {
        if (word.length() % 2 == 0)
        return true;
        return false;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        if (isEven())
            return word + " is even.";
            return word + " is odd. ";
    }
}
```

RUNNER CLASS:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class stringrunner
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(in);

        System.out.print("Enter a String :: ");
        String word = keyboard.next();

        System.out.println(word.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post all relevant code.

Comment: sorry, when I was choosing tags i accidentally posted the post itself

Comment: You're not constructing the `stringoddoreven` class

Comment: Where are you creating a new instance of stringoddoreven? (hint: you're not)

Comment: @DavidWallace: that's why I corrected the title as it's misleading since Strings are in fact neither even nor odd.

Comment: @Jesper It's poorly indented, but there is an `if` there.

Comment: @Jesper: actually, the first `return` in each is nested under the `if` (but I agree it's not indented correctly).

Comment: Horrible indentation...

Comment: Why do people keep deleting their comments after I reply to them?

Comment: @DavidWallace Because I deleted my comment before I saw that you (and 2 other people) had replied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't instantiating (or calling anything in) your `stringoddoreven` class (which should be camel case, like `StringOddOrEven`)

```
System.out.println(new stringoddoreven(word)); // <-- will call toString on 
                                               //     your instance
```

Comment: That line alone wont call the `toString` method, will it? I don't see a method call

Comment: @SterlingArcher It will call `System.out.println(Object)`, and yes that will invoke the `toString()` (implicitly).

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know that. `S.O.P` implicitly calls an objects `.toString` method?

Comment: @SterlingArcher You could try it, or check the [`PrintStream.println(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) Javadoc.

Comment: this seemed to work, the output was correct, although it repeated the String that was entered. EDIT: I should be able to fix it